# What am I doing wrong with these callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
//trigger
fMain(fAfter1());

function fMain(callback()){
    //do stuff here and then...
    callback();
}

function fAfter1(){

}

function fAfter2(){

}
```

It seems that the callback isn't waiting to be triggered like I hoped it would.

Thanks!

Comment: remove the `()` when using functions as a parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition should be `function fMain(callback){`, not `function fMain(callback()){` -- I'm not sure if that's what's causing your problem.